# Issue with Data Load and Index Rebuild in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, teradata, sql-server-2016, ab-initio

Data load for one of the table in SQL Server is taking around **22-24** hrs and index rebuild is taking **4-6** hrs. Below are some additional details about the size and data load process.

- Table Size: 800 GB
- Total No.Of Indexes: 11
- No.Of Partitions on the Table :50
- Frequency of Data Load: Monthly Once
- Data Load Pattern:  Truncate and Load.Disable all Index and then rebuild post data load
- Source System: Teradata
- Target System: SQL SERVER 2016
- ETL Tool: AB-Initio

Please suggest any optimizations options available such that we can reduce the time for data load and index rebuild process.

Comment: Keep the table on Teradata :-)

Comment: Don't Truncate and load. Only load new data.

Comment: New data load is not possible as we dont know which records are getting affected

Comment: Please let me know if there is any optimal approach to handle this load process..

Comment: Loading  800GB data every month does not make sense. You can easily implement Change data capture (CDC) logic in Ab Initio. 

Are you using mfile or serial file?